# JQuery select specific tag

Tags: jquery, events, selector

I'm new to JQuery and I have some troubles to solve this problem. I have to generate input fields from a dynamic List (using ASP.NET MVC4), the point is that I don't know the size of the List in advance.

I generate input boxes like this :

```
<ul>
        @for(int i=0;i< Model.listeVisites.Count;i++)
        {      
            <li><input id="input-visite+@i"  type="text" value="@Model.listeVisites[i]" /></li>
        }
</ul>
```

And I would like to create a button for each input so that when it is clicked, the input field is hidden with .hide(), and the field is set to the empty string. However I can't figure out two things :

1) With Jquery I don't really know how I can link a function to an event. In "normal" javascript I would have added an Onclick attribute to the input fields, but how can I achieve it with Jquery ?

2) What is the simplest and the more conventional way to achieve my goal, considering the dynamic and unpredictible nature of my id names.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, add a `class` or `id` to your `ul` so it can be easily identified. Then try this:

```
$('#myUl li input').each(function() {
    $(this).after($('<button />', { text: 'Hide' }));
});

$('#myUl').on('click', 'button', function() {
    $(this).prev('input').hide();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/hkAuy/1/)

Comment: just add ... look to jquery .prev .after .find .closest for locate (select) your specific (unique) ID element (as selector) in your code for do anything with it

Comment: @Rory Thank you, I'll just adapt it so that it hides also the button and the li. I want the whole line to disappear.

Comment: @user2948152 if you want to hide the `button` and the `li`, change the `hide()` line to this: `$(this).closest('li').hide();`.